# Is TFS Source Control really feasible for Dynamics CRM?

Tags: version-control, tfs, dynamics-crm-2011

I'd really like to get a CRM solution under source control but there are a lot of issues. I was excited to see the SolutionPackager tool - thinking MS finally gave us a way to do this. However the tools to export the solution, extract it to files and check it into source control are not integrated. I'm working on a C# project that ties everything together because it's easier to work with the APIs in a single C# solution than deal with a combination of command line utilities such as tf.exe, PowerShell commandlets and plain old .cmd files.

Source files for plugins and Silverlight pages are easy to deal with but I'm looking to get all of the customizations under source control. SolutionPackager works well for tracking customizations made in the CRM interface, but fails in a lot of other areas. I want to create VS solutions for my web resources and reports but I have issues with the VS project and solution structures. SolutionPackager expects to find things where it puts them for repackaging and I'm sure it would not like to see a bunch of .sln, .csproj and .vspscc files interspersed with them.

I figured putting the VS solutions in a separate folder would be the answer but it's not easy. If I create a project for my web resources and try to put my existing .html, .css and .js files into it it wants to copy those into the project folder. I have to remember to use "Add As Link" each time. Worse yet, if I try to do the same with SSRS reports, the "Add As Link" feature isn't even available.

Has anyone done this successfully? I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: That is the only way unfortunately.
 - export your solution file and extract using PackagerTool,
 - copy all extracted files to the project location,
 - make a check in.

You may have some trouble using the PackagerTool though. For example, you may seem some of the files constantly changing even though you didn't make change effecting them. This is why, packager tool is exporting some of the file content randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen below link but i have not get chance to implement it.when i have try it will post information.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2013/05/17/release-alm-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-crm-solution-lifecycle-management.aspx